# Using ROR instance variable in form tag

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working in ROR(ruby on rails) and I am trying to use a ror variable in form tag, but getting error

here is my code

```
@answers.each do |answer| %>
   <%= form_tag("javascript:save_answer_comment("answer.id")", :id => 'my_answer_comment_form') do %>
            <li>
                    <div class="commenter"></div>   
                    <div class="add_comment">
                        <textarea placeholder="Enter your comment here" class="my_comment"></textarea> 
                    </div>
            </li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I get error on this line "javascript:save_answer_comment("answer.id")"

What is the problem, please help

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to do? What does `"javascript:save_answer_comment("answer.id")"` do?

Comment: The form is submitting to a javascript function and I am trying to pass an id to a Javascript function with form submission

Comment: Try #{answer.id} instead of "answer.id" and see if it works

Comment: Great! I'll put it as an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When placing ruby variables inside a string you need to use interpolation. 
More info: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation

In your code replace

```
"javascript:save_answer_comment("answer.id")"
```

with

```
"javascript:save_answer_comment(#{answer.id})"
```